# AirFlow backfill and catchup - how is it useful?

Tags: airflow

I understand how backfill and catchup work in AirFlow, but what I fail to understand, is how they can be used in a non-redundant way.

In the documentation I read, if I want to backfill say, past 30 days, the identical job will be re-run 30 times, but I imagine that the spoofed backfill date would need to be passed to the job in some way, to prevent that (say, request data from the API only for the spoofed date we are backfilling).

Otherwise running the same job n number of times doesn't bring value of course. Can someone clarify or provide real-life cases for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airlfow provides you the choice of how to execute your workflow.

Lets explain with example.
consider that workflow is suppose to run hourly. If things work as expected every hour there is a new run that process relevant data with hour window.

Now, let consider that something happened and for some reason the workflow did not run for 3 hours.
In that scenario:

1. if you will set `catchup=True` this means that airflow will not skip runs. Airflow will invoke all the 3 missing runs.
2. If you set `catchup=False` this means that airflow will skip the missing runs and will invoke 1 run for the 3 hours window.

The important thing to understand is options 1 and 2 are depended on how you write your DAG.

If your DAG isn't design to consume relevant records in the window than it is pointless to setup `catchup=True`.
I suggest to take a look at [Airflow macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#variables). If your hourly DAG is querying some resource (DB, API, etc..) with search condition as between `{{ data_interval_start }} and {{ data_interval_end }}` then there is a big difference if you guarantee that this window is of 1 hour or it may be larger window in case some runs were not invoked.

Airflow does not bind you to a specific practice of workflow authoring. You can choose the one that works best for your use case.